# SQL query get last value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the last time (by date) that appears a (Empleado) where the value "Entrar" is 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGy0a.png)

```
SELECT '20498090R'
FROM fichajes
WHERE fecha IN (SELECT MAX(fecha) FROM fichajes)
  AND entrada = '1'
```

But this give me the las register where entrada= '1' and I just want to return information if the last entry is 1, not the las entry where entrada ='1'

In this case my last register entrada = "0" so i need no information
What is wrong?

Comment: if you want to find the last time for given Empleado you can use following sql

Comment: It's not about your problem but shouldn't your request be 
    `SELECT empleado FROM fichajes WHERE fecha IN (SELECT MAX(fecha) FROM fichajes) AND entrada = '1' `
??

Comment: To clarify, by "last entry" do you mean the most recent date?

Comment: yes the most recen date for the selected "empleado" @toonice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  following code is for if you want the most recent value of Fecha for a specific employee (in this case "20498090R") if that employee has an entrada value of 1.

```
SELECT maxFecha
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX( fecha ) AS maxFecha,
           entrada AS entrada
    FROM fichajes
    WHERE empleado = '20498090R'
) withEntrada
WHERE entrada = 1;
```

The following code is for if you want the most recent value of Fecha for each employee with a value of entrada equalling 1.

```
SELECT empleado,
       maxFecha
FROM
(
    SELECT empleado AS empleado,
           MAX( fecha ) AS maxFecha,
           entrada AS entrada
    FROM fichajes
    GROUP BY empleado
) withEntrada
WHERE entrada = 1;
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to identify the most recent record for a given employee, and the just check the value of `entrada`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN entrada = '1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS result
FROM fichejes
WHERE Fecha = (SELECT MAX(Fecha) FROM fichejes WHERE empleado = '20498090R')
```

Comment: This would be if it were for the general table I want for the specific case in which the (Employee is 20498090R)

Comment: @Pablo Add a condition to the `WHERE` clause for this employee.

Comment: sorry for my english 
I only want to answer if the last time (time) that appears 20498090R the value entry is 1

Comment: What if several rows have the same max value?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen With this query i get the las time where 'entrada' = `1` but i want nothing because las register in time for 20498090R 'entrada' = '0'   ---> SELECT * FROM fichajes WHERE Empleado = '20498090R' AND entrada = '1' ORDER BY Fecha DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: @jarlh it isn't a problem because y search 'empleado' and 'fecha'

Answer (score 0):

Select the latest record for employee `'20498090R'` (with `LIMIT`). Then select this record only if `entrada = 1`.

```
select *
from fichejes
where (empleado, fecha) in
(
  select empleado, fecha
  from fichejes
  where empleado = '20498090R'
  order by fecha desc
  limit 1
)
and entrada = 1;
```

Comment: With this query i get the las time where 'entrada' = 1 but i want nothing because last register in time for 20498090R 'entrada' = '0' thanks for help

Comment: No you don't. The inner query gives you the employee's last record, which you say has entrada = 0. Then this record gets looked up, but as entrada <> 1, nothing gets selected. Have you even tried the query?

Comment: Hi Thorsten, maybe give a Rex or Fiddle to demonstrate your answer.